# pgettext not showing the untranslated value in django admin

Tags: python, django, translation, gettext

I have a model field:

`title = models.CharField(pgettext_lazy('context', 'title'), max_length=255)`

When I use **ugettext_lazy** it displays the untranslated string. (in this case 'title')

But with **pgettext_lazy** it becomes an empty string. (it hides the title label in the admin)

Is this standard behaviour of pgettext? Am I missing something?

.po file contents:

```
msgctxt "context"
msgid "title"
msgstr ""
```

admin looks like this http://cl.ly/072o1x3p11161X3x3y2c

Comment: Do you have something about source string in .po file? Maybe there's a space symbol as a translation or something like that? pgettext seems to be working fine for me

Comment: The source in my .po files seem normal. I added it to the question.
how did you test it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the solution:

```
pgettext_lazy(u'context', u'title')
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it. pgettext_lazy returns a proxy object. Casting to unicode does the trick:

```
unicode(pgettext_lazy('context', 'title'))
```

EDIT:

This is not the answer. Because this way `manage.py makemessages` doesn't pick up the line as 'marked translated'.